# Множественная перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++

Неправильно сравнивает 2 массива, вместо `false`(`-`) выдает `true`(`+`). В чем проблема? (Функция помечена комментарием)

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyArray
{
    int SizeOfArray;
    int* Arr;
public:
    MyArray() : SizeOfArray(0), Arr(0)
    { }
    MyArray(int SizeOfArray)
    {
        this->SizeOfArray = SizeOfArray;
        Arr = new int[SizeOfArray];
        for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            Arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    void ShowArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            cout << Arr[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int& operator[](int);
    bool operator==(MyArray);
    MyArray operator=(MyArray);

};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    MyArray o1(5), o2(5);
    o1[0] = 5;
    o1[2] = 5;
    o1[1] = 5;
    o1[3] = 5;
    o1[4] = 5;

    o2[0] = 5;
    o2[2] = 5;
    o2[1] = 5;
    o2[3] = 3;
    o2[4] = 6;

    o1.ShowArray();
    o2.ShowArray();

    if (o1 == o2)
    {
        cout << "+" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "-" << endl;

    o1 = o2;

    o1.ShowArray();
    o2.ShowArray();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int& MyArray::operator[](int i)
{
    return Arr[i];
}

bool MyArray::operator==(MyArray obj2)  //неправильный результат работы этой функции     
{
    if (SizeOfArray != obj2.SizeOfArray)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            if (Arr[i] != obj2.Arr[i]) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
}

MyArray MyArray::operator=(MyArray obj2)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        Arr[i] = obj2.Arr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить код:

```
bool MyArray::operator==(const MyArray& obj2) const
{
    if (SizeOfArray != obj2.SizeOfArray)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            if (Arr[i] != obj2.Arr[i]) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Почему так - понятно? :)

Comment: `(const MyArray& obj2) const` - зачем нам `const` и ссылка ? :)

Comment: Потому что вы не собираетесь ничего менять - раз, и не нужно делать копию массива, чтобы убедиться, что он равен другому - два. Общий глобальный совет - почаще используйте `const`, это обычно окупается :) Например, без `const` при возврате массива из функции сравнить бы вы его не могли - только через сохранение в переменной... Но у вас главная ошибка - не там воткнутое `return true`, так что вы сравнивали только первый элемент...

Comment: спасибо, понятно) ошибка-то была в операциях ветвления :)

Comment: ах да, а ссылочка-то нам зачем нужна, поясните

Comment: Еще раз - без нее будет копирование массива. Зачем вам это нужно - лишняя работа? лучше сравнивать элементы прямо на месте; `const` не позволит их случайно изменить.

Comment: Кстати, в операторе присваивания тоже нужно использовать `const Array&` - иначе у вас сначала выполняется копирование, потом копирование копии в новое место, потом промежуточная копия уничтожается...

Comment: подождите,копирование массива? или обьекта?

Comment: А, да. Я и не глянул. У вас некорректность - поверхностное копирование массива в конструкторе копирования по умолчанию - компенсируется отсутствием деструктора (приводящим к утечке памяти).

Comment: в деструкторе записать `delete[] Arr` ?

Comment: Да, но! тогда вы будете обязаны написать корректный копирующий конструктор, корректный оператор присваивания (а не то, что сейчас) - иначе у вас обязательно будут проблемы при работе.

Comment: а в чем его некорректность?

Comment: Потому что сейчас у вас его нет, так что используется сгенерированный - а он просто копирует указатели. Изменяя данные в одном объекте, вы получите изменения и во втором... А потом два деструктора будут удалять один и тот же указатель - и все, приплыли...